# Probability of a ball will be drawn at the same try as its value?

Tags: probability

If I would have a bingo cage with $36$ wooden balls in it, each numbered  $1$ to $36$.  I draw a ball and write the selected number ball on a piece of paper and then replace the ball again in the cage. I do this $36$ times.

What is the probability that at least one ball would be drawn at the same try as its value. For example the $17$th try is the numbered ball $17$.

Regards

Comment: What are your thoughts so far?

Comment: When you draw a ball, it has a $\frac{1}{36}$-chance of having the same number as the number of draw. Do you know how to calculate the rest?

Comment: Hint:  for problems like this it is often easier to work with the complement.  That is, compute the probability that no ball matches its number.

Comment: As lulu mentioned, whenever you see the word "at least", it's very likely you may have to use the complement of the desired event, have that repeat $n$ times and then again take the complement of the whole thing.

Answer (score 1):

First observe that the material of the balls and the type of the cage do not matter.

Second apply the procedure suggested in the comments. The probability that you draw a "false" ball in the $i$-th try is $\frac{35}{36}$ independent of the try count. Thus, the probability that you 36 times draw a "false" ball is $\left(\frac{35}{36}\right)^{36}$. What remains are the cases when at least once a "correct" ball was drawn, so that 
$$
P=1-\left(\frac{35}{36}\right)^{36}\approx 0.63729.
$$

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, I’m impressed! One final question, if I added a blank ball for a total of 37 balls what would be the probability if I draw again 36 times, taking into consideration that the blank ball is there?

Comment: @SergioMunoz Should the ball be counted as "false" or as "correct" when drawn?

Comment: Blank ball is always false as it has no number. Regards

Comment: @SergioMunoz Then just replace (35/36) with (36/37).